# how to make svg addpoint

Tags: svg, point

hi guys  ı loved the example `[`https://codepen.io/SaraSoueidan/pen/24de844274fb139d7eb1702783c9076d `][1](http://%60https://codepen.io/SaraSoueidan/pen/24de844274fb139d7eb1702783c9076d%20%60) but how to add 6 point and make a href in html

Comment: Spell out the question and code here and be sure to explain in details what you are after in your example.

Comment: thank you ı fixed my problem use library https://github.com/softwaretailoring/wheelnav